# SQL count(*) with group by not giving me anything

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that will give me count for how many messages there are but with no luck. The messages are split in parts. All parts of the same message have the same ID.

Here is my table "**messages**"

```
|     Text      |   ID   |   CreatorID  |   Status   |
   Hello Wo..      1234       Martin          OK
   rld! This..     1234       Martin          OK
   is a test!      1234       Martin          OK
   WELCOME p..     9999       Martin         Error
   eople to ..     9999       Martin         Error
   the party!      9999       Martin         Error
```

I'd like to get this information:

```
Total count of messages with CreatorID 'Martin' - 2 messages.
Total count of messages with CreatorID 'Martin' and Status 'Error' = 1 message.
```

I have tried to do this in several ways but none of them seem to be working

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from messages WHERE CreatorID = 'Martin' GROUP BY ID (expecting 2)
SELECT COUNT(*) from messages WHERE CreatorID = 'Martin' AND status = 'Error' GROUP BY ID (expecting 1)
```

Comment: use COUNT(DISTINCT ID) instead of GROUP BY ID

Comment: Try using aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Count(Distinct ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) instead of `Group By`:

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct ID) from messages WHERE CreatorID = 'Martin'
SELECT COUNT(Distinct ID) from messages WHERE CreatorID = 'Martin' AND status = 'Error'
```

You can further go ahead and merge these into single query using conditional aggregation (utilizing [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) function):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS total_messages, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT IF(status = 'Error', ID, NULL)) AS total_Error_messages 
FROM messages 
WHERE CreatorID = 'Martin'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @MartinZeltin happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do both in one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.id)  as num_messages,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN m.status = 'Error' THEN m.id END) as num_error_messages
FROM messages m
WHERE m.CreatorID = 'Martin';
```

If you want these for each `CreatedID`, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT m.CreatorID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT m.id)  as num_messages,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN m.status = 'Error' THEN m.id END) as num_error_messages
FROM messages m
GROUP BY m.CreatorID;
```

Comment: Could you explain what CASE and THEN END does?

Comment: @MartinZeltin . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case.

Comment: Thank you! That's awesome how we can do it in one query!

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't a question. I was saying that it is very nice that we can do it with one query.